# Quarkus Keycloak authenticating users with x509 certificates

Tags: keycloak, quarkus, x509

I have been trying to figure how to get client authentication working using x509 certificates in the Quarkus version of Keycloak.  @dasniko has a helpful video of doing it with [the legacy version of Keycloak](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yq1hzNs1JQU&t=1086s).  I tried to follow what he and the [Keycloak server admin guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_x509) suggests.

The expected behavior, based on @dasniko 's video is a certificate selection window should open up upon visiting the login url.  However,  only the login screen is displayed.

I have created a [simple example](https://github.com/tlann/keycloak-mtls) to demonstrate what I'm attempting.  There is a script to generate the certificates and import them into a jks.  The script then copies the jks files to a directory.  The compose.yml file mounts the cert directory when starting Keycloak up and points Keycloak to them as a keystore and truststore.  Their is also a realm export to configure things.
Has anyone been able to figure this out?  I haven't seen anything helpful on Keycloak's github forums or discourse.

My yaml file looks like the following

```
  services:
    keycloak:
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
      command: [ "start-dev" ]
      environment:
        JAVA_OPTS_APPEND: "-Dcom.redhat.fips=false"
        KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: "false"
        KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
        KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
        KC_LOG_LEVEL: info,org.infinispan:error,org.hibernate:warn
        KC_HTTPS_KEY_STORE_FILE: /genCerts/server-keystore.jks
        KC_HTTPS_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD: changeit
        KC_HTTPS_TRUST_STORE_FILE: /genCerts/truststore.jks
        KC_HTTPS_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD: changeit
        HTTPS_CLIENT_AUTH: require
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
        - 8443:8443
      volumes:
        - ./genCerts:/genCerts
```

Comment: Sounds like a sensible question for the [discussion forum on github](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions) or the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/keycloak-user). --- This question does not seem progrmaming-related and is therefore off-topic here.